# Does the iPhone sdk support l2cap bluetooth sockets?

Tags: iphone, ios4, bluetooth, l2cap

Does the iPhone sdk support l2cap bluetooth sockets?  Any additional information about SDK classes, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: back to the stone age. both iOS and Android have issues in providing something so basic such as complete bluetooth functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 
There are no direct support for Bluetooth APIs in the SDk, 
REfer the game kit programming APIs for application development with Bluetooth for peer-to-peer gaming

Other than than you will have to join the Made for iPod/iPhone/iPad program to get access and develop bluetooth connected accessories

Answer (score 3):

The latest CoreBluetooth does expose L2Cap through CBL2CAPChannel: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbl2capchannel

It can be opened from a CBPeripheral: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/2880151-openl2capchannel

Answer (score 0):

Bad news from MFI FAQ (2014):

**Q:** *I want to develop an accessory that communicates with an Apple device using only **Bluetooth** Low Energy. Do I need to join the MFi Program?*

**A:** *No. Accessories which connect to an Apple device using only Bluetooth Low Energy/BTLE/Bluetooth 4.0 or standard Bluetooth profiles supported by iOS* **are not part of the MFi Program.**

I'm developing an app to connect with a L2CAP device on Android, now I'm studying porting on IOS but I found this issue.

For enabling a device to talk by Bluetooth, it must integrate the Apple authentication chip into device and must be able to connect with built-in Apple's Bonjour discovery service.

No L2CAP for any device... Sorry!

Website: https://mfi.apple.com 
Source: https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#4-2

Comment: I think you are not reading it correctly. If you are using BTLE you don't need to have MFi License / chip